# custom(HEX) formatter C# not working when editing cell of grid control

Tags: c#, formatting, hex, byte

I am using a custom(HEX) formatter in my property grid control to show a field in HEX...

```
public class CustomFormatterHex : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    // implementing the GetFormat method of the IFormatProvider interface
    public object GetFormat(System.Type type)
    {
        return this;
    }

    // implementing the Format method of the ICustomFormatter interface
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt32(arg));
    }
}
```

i make the CustomFormatterHex class and than try to use it when bind complete:

```
        myPropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myObject;            

        BaseRow row = cItems.GetRowByFieldName("MyFieldName");
        if (row != null)
        {
            row.Properties.Format.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Custom;
            row.Properties.Format.Format = new CustomFormatterHex();
        }
```

The "byte" field appears ok in the grid - he looks like HEX (example: if the value is 10, is shown as 0A) but when i try to edit field by clicking in the grid row the value is changed and looks like 10 and i cannot put something like 0B - i should type in "byte" - like 11 except of 0B

please help :(

Comment: Is it possible the grid's cell is set as 'int' type? Can it be set as `string`?

Comment: the grid cell is string,- the data field is byte

Comment: the issue is solved by another way. i am make the TypeConvecterHex delivered from TypeConverter and use [TypeConverter(typeof(TypeConvecterHex))] attribute for my byte field. now it still "byte" value, but looks like "HEX string"